# Topology on the Lie-group based on the Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

By Lie's third theorem, to every finite dimensional Lie-algebra, one can associate a simply connected Lie-group to it. It sounds to me that one can obtain the information about the topology on the Lie-group by its Lie-algebra. Therefore, my question is, is there any direct relation between the topology on the Lie-group and its Lie-algebra?

Comment: @DietrichBurde For the topology of the Lie-group, the maximum information from Lie algebra, which we can extract, is the connectedness?

Comment: No, for example the Lie group $(\Bbb{R}^{\times},\cdot)$ is not connected, but has abelian Lie algebra $\Bbb{R}$. So does the connected Lie group $(\Bbb{R},+)$. Hence the Lie algebra does not say anything about connectedness.